# Apache spark and pyspark in docker container

Tags: python, docker, apache-spark, pyspark, docker-compose

I'm new in spark and I stucked with a problem. I created a cluster in a server from the bitnami/spark image, and an another one which is similar to the apache/spark-py (I rebuilt the whole image from scrach so I can use ubuntu 22.04, and python 3.11). However, when I start the local container, and script inside it which builds the SparkSession in the following way:
`SparkSession.builder.appName("app").master("spark://serverip:7077") .config("spark.jars", "/opt/spark/jars/postgresql-42.2.5.jar") .getOrCreate()`
I got an error:
`WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources`

In the spark UI (port:8080) seems everything fine, I can see every worker, and I also added the port 7077 to the docker-compose. If I remove the master part from the session build, and make it "local" it's also works fine.

I also tried to run the cluster locally, but I have the same error.